# Windows 8 dns hosts file not doing what it is supposed to

Tags: dns, xampp, localhost, wamp, subdomain

I changed my hosts file at:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

to

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 www.david.com
```

everything else is commented with #

I clean the dns with ipconfig /flushdns

However when I put on my chrome browser www.david.com it does not go to my localhost.

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried to ping the server but it does not ping my localhost.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to use the `www` in the hosts file.

Your hosts file should look like this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 david.com
```

When you change the hosts file you need to restart the dnscache service like this

Launch a Windows command windows using the 'Run as Administrator' menu option and then do

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
```

Then use `david.com` in the browser.

For some reason the `www.` is ignored even if you add it.

Comment: I have windows 8 on my computer and my file looks just like you said. I flush the dns, I restarted the dns cache I even clean the browser cache. Still I get the site david.com. I don't get it really.